# How register a new user with domino using c#?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

```
NotesRegistration notesRegistration = lotusNotesServerSession.CreateRegistration();
notesRegistration.RegistrationServer = "servername";
notesRegistration.CreateMailDb = true;
notesRegistration.CertifierIDFile = "cert.id";
NotesDateTime dt = lotusNotesServerSession.CreateDateTime("Today");
dt.SetNow();
dt.AdjustYear(1);
notesRegistration.Expiration = dt;
notesRegistration.IDType = REG_TYPE.ID_HIERARCHICAL;
notesRegistration.IsNorthAmerican = false;
notesRegistration.MinPasswordLength = 5;
notesRegistration.UpdateAddressBook = true;
notesRegistration.StoreIDInAddressBook = true;
notesRegistration.RegisterNewUser("GU", "", "servername", "SA", "", "", "","", "mail\\gsa.nsf", "", "certpassword", "", "");
```

I am registering a new people with by executing the above code the user is created successfully and it was listed under people in domino server admin console. When I try to open a mail file using "Open Mail File" option in domino server console, I am not able to open that and the error says like "You are not authorized to access that database".How can I resolve this issue? whether I am missing anything in the code part?

Comment: Why do you think you (admin) are authorized automatically to access users' mailfiles? Without setting notesRegistration.MailACLManager you simply don't have access to the users' mailfile, so the message is absolutely correct.Use Full Access Administrator if you really need to access the mailfile (beware: in some countries, e.g Germany, this is illegal under certain circumstances)

Comment: @TorstenLink I have to set  MailACLManager to ACLLEVEL_EDITOR for a new user  and i am doing it by notesRegistration.MailACLManager = ACLLEVEL.ACLLEVEL_EDITOR.ToString();  still i am facing the same error. When i try to open the user in lotus notes by using "open other contact" also i am getting same error.

Comment: When i tried to assign owner access notesRegistration.MailOwnerAccess = REG_MAILOWNACL.REG_MAIL_OWNER_ACL_EDITOR;   the database is opened without any issues. Thank You @TorstenLink

Comment: Sorry, but you mix up two different Properties: The one I mentioned is "MailACLManager" to set the Manager of the Database in the ACL (give YOU access to the user mailfile, expects a NAME). The one you use is "MailOwnerAccess" to set the access the user has to his own mailfile (expects an ACLLEVEL). Totally different... but good that you got it sorted out.

Comment: @TorstenLink When i am registering a new user using IBM Domino Admin the InternetAddress is automatically updated using first-name and last-name . But, when  I am registering the a new user using the above program is not automatically updated. If I set MailInternetAddress property then the user is registered with InternetAddress. This there is anyway to automatically set InternetAddress ?

Comment: if you register a new user in the backend, you're code is responsible for the internet address